# How to create function from for each array key/value?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

Before comment please read carefully... Im working on an framework like wordpress widgets and sidebars. These are predefined functions. In our framework I need to pass arguments which create dynamic function definitions. create_function() does not fulfil my requirement.

I have a situation in which I need to create dynamic functions. So, I have created an array which contain function's names. Please refer below example which describe the situation.

E.g.

```
$dynArr = array(
 'function_one',
 'function_another',
 'function_another_one',
);

foreach ($dynArr as $key => $val) {
   function $key() {
       // FUNCTION DESCRIPTION HERE
   }
}
```

Is there any solution to do this with PHP or using wordpress filters etc.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve, how will this be used. My opinion, one function should be enough, you need to use conditionals wisely here. You should not use `create_function` and `eval` at all, you should strickly avoid those

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
$function = function()
{
    echo 'Im annonymous function';
};

$function();
```

PHP 5.3 required to work ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The most universal way to do it is using `eval()`:

```
eval('function abc() { echo "hello"; }');
abc();
```

Propably this is what you need to do as you mentioned wordpress. But I would suggest to go against it, it's inefficient and dangerous, and instead generate a php file instead, if the body of the functions doesn't change that often.